# how to edit and update row values in grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview like this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                OnRowEditing="gvProducts_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvProducts_RowUpdating" CellPadding="4"
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPID" runat="server" Text="Product ID"></asp:Label>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProdID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProdID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPName" runat="server" Text="Product Name"></asp:Label>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProdName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProdName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

and here is the code behind page

```
    protected void gvProducts_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvProducts.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    }

    protected void gvProducts_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        int i = e.RowIndex;
        object control = gvProducts.Rows[i].FindControl("txtProdID");
        //i want to access the new value from the object "control" but i m getting the previous value only
    }
```

Comment: Didn't format the markup in your post?

Comment: @Vijay : Sure from next time as i was not knowing, Thanks!

Comment: Khan; Plz check now as I have update my answer. I hope now it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I tested your code, I do get the modified txtProdID (ProductID, though it is bad idea to let the users edit a ProductID). How are you binding to the datasource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{ 
TextBox txtProdID = (TextBox)gvProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtProdID");
TextBox txtProdName = (TextBox)gvProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtProdName");


//Call update method
Product.Update(txtProdId,txtProdName);

gvProducts.EditIndex = -1;
//Refresh the gridviwe
BindGrid(); 
}
```

Comment: After finding the control(like u did), i am unable to find the new values in the control(txtProdID in ur solution).

Comment: hi all, The mistake i did in Page_Load event. I was binding the gridview every time, now i am restricting it to one time by using if(!isPostBack) condition. The code is working fine now.

Comment: What is the *Product* object in your example?  I don't see it declared anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `e.NewValues` dictionary for updated data.

I've a sample below, the GridView Template is bound to CategoryName.
OnRowUpdating is fired when the 'Edit' button is clicked.
In the RowUpdating event handler, it fetches the CategoryName data to which the textbox is bound to.

Note: Instead of using TextBox in normal mode use Labels.

```
<asp:GridView ID='GridView1' runat='server' DataKeyNames='CategoryID' OnRowUpdating='HandleOnGridViewRowUpdating'
        DataSourceID='ObjectDataSource1' AutoGenerateColumns='false'>
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID='CategoryName' Text='Category' runat='server'></asp:Label>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID='CategoryNameTextbox' Text='<%# Bind("CategoryName") %>' runat='server'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

code-behind:

```
public void HandleOnGridViewRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValues["CategoryName"] != null)
        {
            String newCategoryName = e.NewValues["CategoryName"].ToString();
            // process the data; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: i m getting error : "object reference not set to an instance of object" for the following statement String newCategoryName = e.NewValues["CategoryName"].ToString(); I have the column as CategoryName

Comment: Did you remove the if(.. !=null) check? Is the data bound to the gridview, your gridview markup doesn't say that it is bound to CategoryName. Try something the gridview is bound to in your case ProductID.

Comment: @ vijay : hi vijay, the value in e.NewValues is coming as null

Comment: I tested your code, I do get the modified txtProdID (ProductID, though it is bad idea to let the users edit a ProductID). How are you binding to the datasource?

Comment: @ Vijay : I agree that its bad idea to enable any Id to be editable, but before going to my module i just create one table containing ProdID and prodName. I am calling a function to bind the data. That connect ot sql db and fetch in the dataset. I bind that with my gridview