# How to select all data on Gridview and use their specific cell for updating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm creating a shopping cart and I wanted to update all the data on gridview which were not **Remove**.

here is my shopping cart:

[image]

```
private void quotate()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE transaction_status
                            SET status_of_transaction = @status_of_transaction
                         WHERE transaction_id = @transaction_id
                            AND transaction_number = @transaction_number
                            ", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transaction_id", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transaction_number", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status_of_transaction", "review");


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

How could I update all remaining data on the table because `SelectedRow` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtTransID");
```

[Edit and Update Row Values in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000489/how-to-edit-and-update-row-values-in-grid-view)

Answer (score 1):

> Try to use the for loop 
>   ex:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count;i++) 
    {
      con.Open();
      cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE transaction_status
                        SET status_of_transaction = @status_of_transaction
                        WHERE transaction_id = @transaction_id
                        AND transaction_number = @transaction_number
                        ", con);


     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transaction_id",GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transaction_number",GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status_of_transaction", "review");
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close(); 
     }
```